# Use Javascript to search HTML table and keep the complete table row where matches are found and remove the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Extremely new to Javascript, somewhat new to HTML so any help is great.

I have an HTML table that I have created and would like to tie a javascript script to it which would allow me to search in my search box, and any entries not matching would disappear and matches would stay on screen with the entire row showing. I currently have it so I can search for a keyword, but just the word appears and everything else disappears leaving whatever keyword found brought over to the first column.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-search.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css"> table {
font-size: 12px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table td {
padding: 4px;
margin: 3px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
table th {
background-color: #104E8B;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<body>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">

  <table class="searchable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>High-Level Category</th>
    <th>Device Type</th>
    <th>Hostname</th>
    <th>IP Address</th>
    <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Organizational Unit</th>
    <th>Organizational Unit Email</th>
    <th>Universal Forwarder or Syslog?</th>
    <th>In PCI?</th>
    <th>Notes:</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Security Device</td>
    <td>Firewall</td>
    <td>ITFirewall1</td>
    <td>1.1.1.1</td>
    <td>User1</td>
    <td>Information Technology</td>
    <td>test@test.com</td>
    <td>Syslog</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Security Device</td>
    <td>Firewall</td>
    <td>ITFirewall2</td>
    <td>2.2.2.2</td>
    <td>User2</td>
    <td>Program Development</td>
    <td>test2@test2.com</td>
    <td>Syslog</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

That is my table pointing to jquery and my searchable javascript file.  The following is what I have for my javascript that does the searching:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $rows = $('table td');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();
});

});
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  All help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, just change the code `var $rows = $('table td');` to `var $rows = $('table tr');` to make this work. And ideally you should show the table header always. For that you can use `var $rows = $('table tr:has(td)');`

Comment: Wow, it works! Lol.  However when I search for something my header disappears.  Any thoughts as to how to keep that as well after conducting a search?  Thank you so much!

Comment: Use `$('table tr:gt(0)')` so it doesn't include the header row. Or give your data rows a class and use `$('table tr.dataclass')`.

Comment: @Zach Glad it helped. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark as accepted.

Comment: Or look for rows in `<tbody>`

Answer (score 0):

If using a plugin is an option, I suggest using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) don't reinvent the wheel :)

Here is an example of how the search works:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: Wow, how have I not seen this through my Google adventures?!  That's Great!  I'll have to look at implementing that.  Thank You!

Comment: This is absolutely the best plugin for any kind of tables, It has so many features and plugins, the basic setup is quite simple. Take a look at their documentation, they have a ton of examples. And accept this answer if it does what you are asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

`.hide()` is equivalent to css `display:none` (as opposed to `visibility:hidden`) - the hidden element occupies no space, so everything else moves. In this snippet, I replaced `.hide` with `.css("opacity","0.1")`. I think this is what you wanted to acheive.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var $rows = $('table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.css("opacity","1").filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).css("opacity","0.1");
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-search.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css"> table {
font-size: 12px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table td {
padding: 4px;
margin: 3px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
table th {
background-color: #104E8B;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<body>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">

  <table class="searchable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>High-Level Category</th>
    <th>Device Type</th>
    <th>Hostname</th>
    <th>IP Address</th>
    <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Organizational Unit</th>
    <th>Organizational Unit Email</th>
    <th>Universal Forwarder or Syslog?</th>
    <th>In PCI?</th>
    <th>Notes:</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Security Device</td>
    <td>Firewall</td>
    <td>ITFirewall1</td>
    <td>1.1.1.1</td>
    <td>User1</td>
    <td>Information Technology</td>
    <td>test@test.com</td>
    <td>Syslog</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Security Device</td>
    <td>Firewall</td>
    <td>ITFirewall2</td>
    <td>2.2.2.2</td>
    <td>User2</td>
    <td>Program Development</td>
    <td>test2@test2.com</td>
    <td>Syslog</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: That is really close.  I was actually looking to have the entire row visible, for instance if I searched for 1.1.1.1 I would see that entire row, and the other row would fade away/disappear.  Thanks for the information though! Learning a lot through this.

Comment: I amended the snippet when,  following Hector's post below, I realised I had not fixed the whole row visibility.